# Where do I put command arguments in a youtube-dl python script?

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I'm usually using youtube-dl with terminal like this

`youtube-dl -o '%(uploader)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s' URL`

To get my output named like this: "Channel name - title.mp4"… and it works great for a single video but if I'd like to use this python script to download my subs provided by [Mewfree](https://github.com/mewfree/youtube-dl-subscriptions):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import opml
import feedparser
import youtube_dl
import sys
from glob import glob
from pprint import pprint

if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    raise Exception('Must be using Python 3')

from time import time, mktime, strptime
from datetime import datetime

if len(glob('last.txt')) == 0:
    f = open('last.txt', 'w')
    f.write(str(time()))
    print('Initialized a last.txt file with current timestamp.')
    f.close()

else:
    f = open('last.txt', 'r')
    content = f.read()
    f.close()

    outline = opml.parse('subs.xml')

    ptime = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(float(content))
    ftime = time()

    urls = []

    for i in range(0,len(outline[0])):
        urls.append(outline[0][i].xmlUrl)

    videos = []
    for i in range(0,len(urls)):
        print('Parsing through channel '+str(i+1)+' out of '+str(len(urls)), end='\r')
        feed = feedparser.parse(urls[i])
        for j in range(0,len(feed['items'])):
            timef = feed['items'][j]['published_parsed']
            dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(timef))
            if dt > ptime:
                videos.append(feed['items'][j]['link'])

    if len(videos) == 0:
        print('Sorry, no new video found')
    else:
        print(str(len(videos))+' new videos found')

    ydl_opts = {'ignoreerrors': True}

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download(videos)

    f = open('last.txt', 'w')
    f.write(str(ftime))
    f.close()
```

I have a problem because I don't know anything about python and I can't figure where and how to put my options properly. Of course I've figured it would be somewhere around here:

```
  ydl_opts = {'ignoreerrors': True}
```

Since `'ignoreerrors'` from the python script reflects the `--ignore-errors` or `-i` option from [the youtube-dl doc](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#readme) so I guess I should have something like `'output'` around there but I don't know how to add my options `'%(uploader)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s'` and everything I tried failed, so can someone who actually knows how it works tell me what I should do, please?

Comment: it's described in the docs here: https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#embedding-youtube-dl, which links to an example: https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/3e4cedf9e8cd3157df2457df7274d0c842421945/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L137-L312

Comment: Thanks a lot, I missed that second link, I edited the python script like so:     `ydl_opts = {'ignoreerrors': True,
                'outtmpl': '%(uploader)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s'}` and it works :)

Answer (score 5):

A big thank you to c2huc2hu for the second link he pointed me to, I was looking for `'output'` while it was `'outtmpl'` so I modified the script like so:

```
ydl_opts = {'ignoreerrors': True, 'outtmpl': '%(uploader)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s'}
```

And it works like I wanted it to.